# Opencover orderby issue

Tags: c#, linq, opencover

OpenCover was running fine until I replace this line of code :

```
myObject = myObjectRepository.SelectAll().ToList();
```

by

```
myObject = myObjectRepository.SelectAll().OrderBy(x => x.MyProp).ToList();
```

and then I loose the opencover's report :

> No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common
>   reasons are:
>       1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
>       output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
>       2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
>       guide and the -register switch.

Does anybody can explain that to me?

Comment: Try doing a clean and a full rebuild and check that your PDBs are generated correctly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is happening on our continuous deployment platform. The project is rebuild from scratch. The PDB are generated correctly.

Comment: What does the xml file say why the assemblies weren't  covered? You could raise an issue with OpenCover but you'll need to provide a repeatable example. The issue however is more likely environmental (local to your setup) so unless you are willing to give someone access your CD environment it'll probably go unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

I was using an old version (4.5.3522).

I updated to the version 4.6.519 and this problem disappeared.